# How to assign two consecutive inputs to two different variables?

Tags: python

I have been coding in Python for about 4 months now but I saw a very simple problem on Hackerrank . com which I could not solve. The problem asked to print the sum of the two consecutive inputs from stdin through stdout. Here is the sollution given by hackerrank but I don't undrestand why it works. Why don't both variables get overwritten and get the value of the second input?

Here is solution given by Hackerrank:

```
def solveMeFirst(a,b):
  return a+b


num1 = input()
num2 = input()
res = solveMeFirst(num1,num2)
print res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `input()`, the python interpreter waits for an input, so you get two inputs for the two calls which will be stored in their appropriate variables (num1, num2).

Answer (score 0):

This question shows that you are not only new to Python, but also to programming.

Here this solution has 2 input statements. That means the program will prompt for 2 inputs, in 2 lines. So that, the first input will be stored as num1 and the second one will be stored as num2.